# Maven- Ignore empty/no `main` directory

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, cucumber-java

I have a Cucumber test project in Maven that is only meant to have test code- it does not produce any library or code on its own.

This works great, however, produces a rather annoying warning in the output:

`[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!`

I am running my Cucumber tests via `mvn verify`

How can I tell Maven to ignore the fact that I don't have a `main` folder? I've done it before but can't recall how and don't have access to that codebase anymore, and can't find anything on Google where the fix isn't related to malformed java project structure.

Comment: Which Maven command do you run?

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje `mvn verify`

Comment: You need to make the Maven Jar plugin skip it's execution if the jar file would be empty https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#skipIfEmpty

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje Thanks, that did it, feel free to make an answer and I'll mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell the Maven Jar Plugin to [skip execution if the jar file would be empty](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#skipIfEmpty). I.e:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <skipIfEmpty>true</skipIfEmpty>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```